# Poshytip plugin in dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using [poshyTip tool tip plugin](http://vadikom.com/tools/poshy-tip-jquery-plugin-for-stylish-tooltips/) .

This is the function called in document ready:

```
$('#contentBoxContent div.schedule > a').poshytip({
    content: scheduleDiv,
    showOn: 'none',
    alignTo: 'target',
    alignX: 'left',
    alignY: 'center',
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    liveEvents: true
});

$('#contentBoxContent div.schedule').on('click', 'a', function(){
      $(this).poshytip('show');
});
```

but it's not working on dynamically created elements.

Does any fixes available for this?

div structure is like this :

```
<div class="divId3 displayBlock">
    <div class="mp_t_cnt_1">4</div>
    <div class="mp_t_cnt_2"><a href="Javascript:void(0);">zz5</a></div>
    <div class="mp_t_cnt_3"><a href="Javascript:void(0);">zz5</a></div>
    <div class="mp_t_cnt_4"><span>English (USA)</span></div>
    <div id="tipBox2" class="mp_t_cnt_5">
    <a href="Javascript:void(0)" title="Total Keywords">0</a>
    </div>
   <div class="mp_t_cnt_6">xyz</div>
   <div class="mp_t_cnt_7">
      <div class="f_left_pding"><input type="radio"></div>
      <div id="tipBox1" class="f_left schedule">
         <a class="clck" href="Javascript:void(0)" id="clk1Btn185"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="f_left">
         <a class="close_1" href="Javascript:void(0)"></a>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

On Ajax Response this complete div structrue is newly added.

Have tried `.on` in jQuery on dynamically created elemetns but it doesn't show up.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add more code? On the part where dynamic elements are added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `liveevents:true` option for dynamically created elements.

```
$('#contentBoxContent .schedule > a').poshytip({
    content: scheduleDiv,
    showOn: 'none',
    alignTo: 'target',
    alignX: 'left',
    alignY: 'center',
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
    liveEvents: true
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khNHj/)

For manual trigger event with LiveEvents if it is not working, try a hack by initializing it if not initialized already.

```
$('#contentBoxContent').on('click', 'a', function () {
    if (!$(this).data('poshytip')) // See if it is initialized 
      $(this).poshytip({
        showOn: 'none',
        className: 'tip-darkgray',
        alignTo: 'target',
        alignX: 'left',
        alignY: 'center',
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0
    });
    $(this).poshytip('show');
});
```

Comment: @Arul where did you update the code? How are you triggering it.. You need to add complete info.

Comment: check now, have altered my question with mmore code details and div structrue dats been added newly

Comment: See my answer update. Try that option. http://jsfiddle.net/kGnAP/. It is because it needs to get intialized there is some bug in liveEvents as it works only for non manual triggers. SO on click initialize it checking for data('poshytip') if unavailable.

Comment: have tried ur codec ... its not working even after initialize ...  jsfiddle.net/kGnAP

Comment: hey noticed the problem ... 
    $('#contentBoxContent div.schedule').on('click', 'a', function()   {
 console.log('arul');
    });

its not printing anything in console after elements created dynamically ...

Comment: @Arul It should be  `$('#contentBoxContent').on('click', 'div.schedule a',` in your case since schedule div is created dynamically.